# How can I get input tags with title attributes that contain "&nbsp;"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following input tag in my dom and unable to add classes and/or ids:

```
<input type="radio" title="&nbsp;">
```

When I try

```
$('input[title=" "]')
```

or

```
$('input[title="&nbsp;"]')
```

it does not return anything. Can I pull this based on that title?

Comment: There are other input elements on the dom with a variety of entries, so containing " " does not work either.

Comment: Frankly... sounds like a really really bad idea.

Comment: @MarcDix - Frankly, I don't disagree. The situation happenstances it's need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selectors didn't work because you didn't use the proper symbol. The title attribute gets any html entities decoded, so `&nbsp;` is going to get decoded to the actual symbol   (ascii code 160). So that means the `&nbsp;` text isn't going to match it, neither will a regular space  (ascii code 32).

On a Windows OS you can type <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0160</kbd> to get the symbol. On other OS you will need to find the equivalent key combo, or copy paste from a character map.

```js
console.log( "Number of inputs with regular space: ", $('input[title=" "]').length );
console.log( "Number of inputs with &nbsp; text: ", $('input[title="&nbsp;"]').length );
console.log( "Number of inputs with &nbsp; symbol: ", $('input[title=" "]').length );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Regular space in title -->
<input type="checkbox" title=" "> 

<!-- non-break space html entity -->
<input type="checkbox" title="&nbsp;"> 

<!-- encoded html entity which will match &nbsp;  -->
<input type="checkbox" title="&amp;nbsp;">
```

Comment: I feel like my answer is here... but can't seem to get alt0160 to work!

Comment: Are you on a Windows OS? And to do it you hold Alt down, and on the keypad hit 0, then 1, then 6, then 0, and then let go of Alt

Comment: Mac. I was googling and found http://design215.com/toolbox/alt_codes.php.

I am just gonna say right now.... I have done things with javascript that I am not proud of.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Could you please describe how you found out that it's ASCII 160 instead of a regular space? console f. e. renders it like a regular space.

Comment: And is there a way to escape this in the js so it at least doesn't look like a space?

Comment: @MarcDix, you just have to look it up in any [character reference document](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), they will tend to show either the unicode number or equivalent. In the linked document it shows various escaped versions, one being the decimal numeric reference, where it is `&#` followed by the unicode number and then `;`

Comment: @notthehoff, if you want you can use an escape character in front of it like "\", so it would end up looking like: `$('input[title="\ "]')` other than that I do not know

Answer (score 1):

Use the following trick with JQuery's `filter()` function and `RegExp.test` function to get input tags with title attributes that contain `&nbsp;`:

```
var inputs = $("input[title]").filter(function(i){
    return /\u00A0/.test($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

---

```
$("input[title*=' ']");
```

To get input elements with title attributes that contains a "regular" space use the following:

> The **[attribute*=value]** selector matches every element whose attribute
>   value containing a specified value.

Answer (score 1):

Would it suffice to select all non-blank title attributes?

```js
$('input:not([title=""])').click(function(){
     alert('non-blank title');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" title="&nbsp;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
var isFound = $('[title=" "]').length === 1;

if (isFound) console.log('Element is found.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="&nbsp;"></div>
```

This subtle difference is to put an actual `&nbsp;` not a space character into selector.

Comment: That is one of the scenarios I tried and is in the original question... unless something is getting lost in translation.

Comment: @notthehoff Your selector contains a regular space, not an `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unwieldy can try a function to return the value of the title attribute and use that. If you are using this in a normal page, you can swap getTitle parameter below for a more specific selector like ID.

```
function getTitle(selector) {
return $(selector).attr('title');
}

$('input[title=' + getTitle('input[type="radio"]') + ']');
```

Comment: If their input is the first input radio button in the document, then this will not work. Also if they were able to do `input[type="radio"]` why would then then get the title and then try to select it a different way when they already have a reference to it

Comment: Yeah, I should've probably clarified that the code is specific to the example. In order for the code to work in a real environment, you would need a more specific selector, and if it's a radio button, you should ostensibly have an id.